# Initialize Derived Class through Database in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

Assuming I have an Object Car with one property: Model

I would populate the object using the database as follows:

```
Public Class Car

    Public Property Model() As String
        Get
            Return _Model
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Model = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Model As String

    Private Sub SetObjectData(ByVal theObjReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader)
        Try
            Me._Model = theObjReader("Model").ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Unable to Initialize Car.")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Car_ID As Integer)
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(DBTool.DataConnectionString)
        Try
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            cmd = New SqlCommand("getCarByCar_ID", connection)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car_ID ", Car_ID)

            connection.Open()
            Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Do While objReader.Read()
                SetObjectData(objReader)
            Loop

            objReader.Close()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now, lets assume for the sake of the argument that this class is wrapped in a DLL.

What I wish to do is to inherit it, while expending my properties. For instance, lets say we want to have a new Object "Expensive_Car" with a new property "Price".

How can I utilize the previous Car object and initialize this derived class in the most "organized" way without writing code twice? The field "Price" is saved in the same SQL table as the field "Model". Of course we need to obtain the "Price" from the Database, just like we pulled Model.

My goal is to utilize existing classes and to expend them using new derived classes without changing the parent class at all. The SQL database structure can change using additional fields as needed.

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider one of the many ORMs out there like Entity Framework or NHibernate.

If you really want a roll-your-own approach the simplest way from here is probably to add two  `protected overridable` methods to the base class, one to create the SqlCommand object with the correct stored proc name and the other to load properties specific to derived classes.

You should probably also wrap the creation of connection, command and data reader objects in `Using` statements to make sure everything gets cleaned up correctly.

Here's a c# example because my VB.Net is really rusty:

```
public class Car
{
  public Car(int carId) {
    CarId = carId;
    LoadProperties();
  }

  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }

  protected virtual SqlCommand CreateCommand() {
    // Override this method in derived classes to call a different procedure.
    return new SqlCommand("getCarByCar_ID");
  }

  protected virtual void LoadMoreProperties(SqlDataReader reader)
  {
    // Override this method in derived classes to load additional properties.
  }

  private void LoadProperties() {
    using( var connection = new SqlConnection(DBTool.ConnectionString) ) {

      using( cmd = CreateCommand() ) {
        using( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
          // Read Car specific properties

          Model = // get model from reader.


          LoadMoreProperties(reader);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public class ExpensiveCar : Car {

  public decimal Price { get; set; }

  protected override SqlCommand CreateCommand() {
    return new SqlCommand("getExpensiveCarByCar_ID");
  }

  protected override void LoadMoreProperties(SqlDataReader reader) {
    Price = // get price from reader.
  }
}
```

It won't compile but should give you the idea. You want to make just the parts that can change overridable - calling a different stored proc and loading the properties specific to the derived class.

Comment: I want to reduce the amount of "duplicated" code. Overriding the methods when all I need to do is initialize certain properties, seems to defeat the purpose. I guess it is the simplest way, but isn't a more effective way?

Comment: I've added an example of what I mean. You should have very little duplicated code.